# Create image View show more

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I want to create a view like this one:

[image]

I am using a Flatlist in which all the data is coming including these thumbnails. This thumbnail is a array of objects from where I fetch image's name and display.

I want to use this inside a FlatList where all my data is coming or I just need a dummy code to implement this feature in react native

Right now I am trying to implement it like this:

```
<View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
            {data.gallery.map((each,index)=>{
              console.log('thubnails ******* ', each);
              <Image source={{uri: Connection.getMedia()+each.name}} style={{height:Constants.BaseStyle.DEVICE_HEIGHT/100 * 10, width:Constants.BaseStyle.DEVICE_WIDTH/100 * 10}} resizeMode='stretch' />
            })}
          </View>
```

Inside data.gallary all the thumbnails are present and data is coming from props.

Answer (score 1):

Sample code from the above details.

**Inside render**:

```
  <FlatList
    data={this.props.sampleData}    // sample data should be a array of objects
    renderItem={this.renderImage}
  />
```

**renderImage function**:

```
  renderImage = ({ item }) => (
    <Image source={{ uri: Connection.getMedia()+item.name }}
      style={{height:Constants.BaseStyle.DEVICE_HEIGHT/100 * 10, 
      width:Constants.BaseStyle.DEVICE_WIDTH/100 * 10}} 
      resizeMode='stretch' 
    />
  );
```

> You can also use Dimensions for getting device height and width.